# IPAddress to CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, ip-address, cultureinfo

I need to convert an IP Address into a CultureInfo object.  I've been able to convert the IP Address to it's two digit Country Code which can be used to create a RegionInfo object.  At this point I'm stuck. It doesn't appear that you can create a CultureInfo object without the locale or the LCID.

Comment: This mapping is not reliable. It is only the mapping to the Internet Service Provider who handed out the block of IP addresses.Those addresses don't always remain in the country which issued them.

Comment: That is ok. I'm using an IP lookup database that is updated monthly.

Comment: No, it's not ok. The lookup database may, for instance, tell you that a particular IP address was issued in England, but won't tell you that a UK company has used half of the block of addresses they were given as addresses for their US subsidiary (which would route through their private network - true story).

Comment: The code you need is in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469540/get-nativeenglishname-from-iso-currency-symbol-without-dependency-to-the-current/2469874#2469874

Comment: What is the best way to detect a user's country/language? Would it be best to only use the Request.UserLanguages to determine this?

Answer (score 1):

You are right.You cant get CultureInfo object without the locale or the LCID.If you can live with a little margin of inaccuracy you can try this

[Get language and country from a browser](http://madskristensen.net/post/Get-language-and-country-from-a-browser-in-ASPNET.aspx)

Comment: I'm already using this as a secondary method. I need to use ip to more accurately identify users.

Comment: I hope it's not for language selection. Nothing is more annoying that being shown a web page in a particular language just because you're traveling abroad.